# Get node data into a string JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to place retrieved data into a string or possibly an array, and be able to print it out onto a page. This is what I have so far but it doesnt work. Can anyone please tell me how to place the node.data into a string or array form?

```
`function neww(node) {
    if (node.nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        var a=node.data;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =a;
    }}`
```

Comment: I don't see a problem in Chrome when I pass in a DOM `Text` object created by `document.createTextNode`: https://jsfiddle.net/gj8b42zv/ What are you using as an argument for `neww`? What browser are you using?

Comment: function getT() {
    neww(w.document.body); also I am using firefox

Comment: `document.body` is not a text node (note that `document.body == Node.ELEMENT_NODE`), so your function does nothing after the `if` check fails. You designed your function to work only on text nodes, so it seems like doing nothing on a non-text node is exactly what you wanted. What do you *actually* want to do? What *should* happen when you pass `body` into `neww`? Should you get a complete reproduction of `body` inside the div, or only the text?

Comment: okay I am getting words from another page and adding them to a string

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not assigning it to a var on window? (maybe you don't want a global var?)

```
`<script>window.INITIAL_STATE = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}</script>`
```

Comment: I cant use jQuery can you please explaion?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, there's no jQuery here, that's a variable in an ES6 string https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this accurately. You didn't provide this function's context.

As I see it, your function should work fine. Other parts of your code must be breaking it.

**My first guess** -- you're calling this function *before the page loads*. That is, you're trying to insert text into an element. However, that element hasn't even been created yet.

---

If that is the case (you didn't provide context, so I don't know), then you should use the `window.onload` function. This would ensure that all elements load before attempting to manipulate them.

Here is an example:

```
function insertNodeTextIntoDemoElement(node) {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    const nodeText = node.data;
    const demoElement = document.getElementById('demo');
    demoDiv.textContent = nodeText;
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  // Other code...
  const exampleNode = document.createTextNode('Hello World!');
  insertNodeTextIntoDemoElement(exampleNode);
  // Other code...
};
```

---

This is the best answer I can provide, given your limited information. If you could show more of your program/give more information, I could provide  a better answer.